# NativeScript Angular RadCalendar

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a problem adding the RadCalendar module to my NativeScript Projekt.

How I implemented the module:

> I followed the nativescript docs and executed tns plugin add nativescript-ui-calendar in my project. Afterwards I added the NativeScriptUICalendarModule to the imports of the module I wanted to use the Calendar in and added the XML Tag in the template file.

What I tried to fix it:

> I deleted node_modules, platforms and executed ns clean to clean the project. Also tried downgrading the calendar npm version. Also tried adding the NativeScriptUICalendarModule  to app.module.ts but I get the same error anyways.

The error I get:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function
System.err: TypeError: _nativescript_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Property is not a constructor
System.err: File: (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:147336:49)
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/ui-calendar.common.js(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:147336:50)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:148708:77)
System.err:     at ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/ui-calendar.js(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:150998:30)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/angular/fesm2015/nativescript-ui-calendar-angular.js(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vend
or.js:146896:82)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at ./app/app.module.ts(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:166:90)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:209:73)
System.err:     at ./main.ts(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:268:30)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at checkDeferredModules(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:44:23)
System.err:     at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:31:19)
System.err:     at (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
System.err:     at require(:1:266)
System.err:
System.err:
System.err: TypeError: _nativescript_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Property is not a constructor
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function
System.err: TypeError: _nativescript_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Property is not a constructor
System.err: File: (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:147336:49)
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/ui-calendar.common.js(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:147336:50)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:148708:77)
System.err:     at ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/ui-calendar.js(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:150998:30)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/angular/fesm2015/nativescript-ui-calendar-angular.js(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vend
or.js:146896:82)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at ./app/app.module.ts(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:166:90)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:209:73)
System.err:     at ./main.ts(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:268:30)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at checkDeferredModules(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:44:23)
System.err:     at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:31:19)
System.err:     at (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
System.err:     at require(:1:266)
System.err:
System.err:
System.err: TypeError: _nativescript_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Property is not a constructor
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6837)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:244)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1951)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function
System.err: TypeError: _nativescript_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Property is not a constructor
System.err: File: (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:147336:49)
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/ui-calendar.common.js(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:147336:50)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:148708:77)
System.err:     at ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/ui-calendar.js(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vendor.js:150998:30)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/angular/fesm2015/nativescript-ui-calendar-angular.js(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/vend
or.js:146896:82)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at ./app/app.module.ts(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:166:90)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at fn(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
System.err:     at (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:209:73)
System.err:     at ./main.ts(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:268:30)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
System.err:     at checkDeferredModules(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:44:23)
System.err:     at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/runtime.js:31:19)
System.err:     at (file:///data/user/0/org.nativescript.TestProject/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
System.err:     at require(:1:266)
System.err:
System.err:
System.err: TypeError: _nativescript_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Property is not a constructor
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:674)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:666)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1193)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6832)
System.err:     ... 8 more
```

Tracking.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";

import { TrackingRoutingModule } from "./Tracking-routing.module";
import { TrackingComponent } from "./Tracking.component";
import { NativeScriptUICalendarModule } from "nativescript-ui-calendar/angular";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        TrackingRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptUICalendarModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        TrackingComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class TrackingModule { }
```

Tracking.component.html

```
<ActionBar>
    <!--
    Use the NavigationButton as a side-drawer button in Android
    because ActionItems are shown on the right side of the ActionBar
    -->
    <NavigationButton ios:visibility="collapsed" icon="res://menu" (tap)="onDrawerButtonTap()"></NavigationButton>
    <!--
    Use the ActionItem for IOS with position set to left. Using the
    NavigationButton as a side-drawer button in iOS is not possible,
    because its function is to always navigate back in the application.
    -->
    <ActionItem icon="res://menu" android:visibility="collapsed" (tap)="onDrawerButtonTap()"
                ios.position="left">
    </ActionItem>
    <Label text="Settings1"></Label>
</ActionBar>

<GridLayout class="page__content">
    <RadCalendar></RadCalendar>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: What version of ns are you using. I don't think the Calendar has been ported to ns8 yet.

Comment: I dont realy know which version it is but I guess that might be the problem :/ cuz my package json says "nativescript-angular": "~8.21.0", is that the version? Or is it   "tns-core-modules": "~6.5.0" ? (tns-android and tns-ios are on 6.5.0 as well)

Comment: After additional thought, I don't think that is the problem. It should work with NS8. But it looks like you are running NS6 anyway.